# Is it OK to use two consecutive 'that' in a sentence?

Tags: american-english, british-english, subcontinental-english, contemporary-english, literary-english

Is the usage of 2 consecutive 'that' in the following sentence correct, because it looks a bit odd? Should these be separated by comma perhaps?

"While I agree that strength and size definitely gives an advantage but I don't believe **that that** advantage holds up against a highly skilled fighter!"

Comment: What makes you think it is/isn’t?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the first things writers learn is the word 'That' is commonly used where it is not needed.  I would say in this sentence, there is no need for the first and second 'that'. The sentence works fine without it.

"While I agree strength and size definitely give an advantage, I don't believe that advantage holds up against a highly skilled fighter!"